# Удаление массива из сессии в Yii2

Tags: сессия, yii2

Пытаюсь сделать удаление массива из сессии в Yii2 с помощью ajax.

$match_id - это id матча который прилетает по нажатию кнопки.приходит все правильно.
['coupons'] - сессия сама по себе содержит массивы.с ключом $match_id и значением является тоже массив.
вид сессии вот такой

```
[
46 => [
    'match_id' => '46'
    'option' => '1'
    'homeTeam' => 'Team1'
    'awayTeam' => 'Spartak'
    'matchDate' => '2015-05-08 03:20:00'
    'optionId' => 'Ev sahibinin qələbəsi'
    'coefficient' => 1
     ]
]
```

вот мой код в контроллере.не могу найти проблему..

```
  public function actionRemove()
{
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
    {
        $match_id = $_POST['match_delete'];

        $session = Yii::$app->session['coupons'];

        if(isset($session))
        {
               if(isset($match_id)){
                    unset($session[$match_id]);
                }
        }
        //die('1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В yii используется магия [по первому индексу/ключу](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Session.php#L861), т.е. Вы не сможете удалить вложенные значения. Вы вернули обыкновенный массив: `$session = Yii::$app->session['coupons'];` эквивалентен `$session = $_SESSION['coupons']`. 
А именно:

```
$session = $_SESSION['coupons'];    
unset($session[46]);

var_dump($_SESSION['coupons']);
```

Значения сессии естественно не изменились. Впрочем, можно это исправить добавлением явной ссылки `$session = &$_SESSION['coupons'];`, но с API yii такая фишка не пройдёт.

**Решения:**

1 Нативный способ доступа к сессиям:

```
unset($_SESSION['coupons'][$match_id]);
```

> Нужно быть острожным, если вы используйте иной обработчик сессий (не файловый), к примеру, Redis, MongoDB, DB,....

2 Получить все данные сессии -> исправить -> добавить через данную обёртку/API

```
unset($_SESSION['coupons'][$match_id]);
$session = Yii::$app->session;
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
   $session[$key] = $value;
}
```

Текущий подход позволяет учесть обработчик. Настоятельно рекомендую делать именно так, ибо неизвестно, что будет завтра, возможно, Вы или кто-то другой пожелает использовать иной обработчик.

**P.S.** Если бы в Yii использовалось нечто [подобное](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-helpers/blob/master/src/ArrayHelper.php#L125), то тогда можно было удалить элемент через цепочку ключей:

```
Yii::$app->session->remove("coupons.{$match_id}");
```

Но увы.

Comment: спасибо большое.метод сработал.)